# How to assign firestore data field to a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase collection 'messages', and I add documents into it:

```
this.afs.collection('messages').add({ 'qn': message, 'student': this.student, 'upvotes': this.upvote });
```

The upvotes field is set by a upvote or downvote button. When either of them are clicked, I call this method:

```
increment(messageId) { //decrement(messageId) for the downvote button
this.upvote += 1; //-=1 for the downvote button   
this.messageDoc = this.afs.doc('messages/' + messageId);
this.message = this.messageDoc.valueChanges();
this.afs.doc('messages/' + messageId).update({
  upvotes: this.upvote
});
}
```

The problem with this is, I defined the upvotes variable as: `private upvote: number = 0;`

This means that if I reload the page and click upvote or downvote, the value will just increase or decrease starting from 0 again, as the variable upvote is not assigned the actual database value. I want to fix this by assigning the data in the upvotes field of the document into the upvote variable - how can I do this?

Edit: Managed to make it work using this

```
increment(messageId) {
this.upvote += 1;
let self = this;
let messageDoc = firebase.firestore().collection('messages').doc(messageId);

return firebase.firestore().runTransaction(function (transaction) {
  return transaction.get(messageDoc).then(function (sfDoc) {
    let upVote = sfDoc.data().upvotes + self.upvote;
    transaction.update(messageDoc, { upvotes: upVote });
    self.upvote = 0;
  });
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Transaction failed: " + err);
});
}
```

Comment: i thinks you need to give `private upvote: number = 1;` as default, in the increment function you are getting the value and +/- the value with `upvote`.you don't need this `this.upvote += 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Transactions` for that

```
let self = this;
let messageDoc = firebase.firestore().collection('messages').doc(messageId);

return firebase.firestore().runTransaction((transaction) => {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(messageDoc).then((sfDoc) => {
        let upVote = sfDoc.data().upvotes + self.upvote;
        transaction.update(messageDoc, { upvotes: upVote });
    });
  }).then(() => {
      console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Transaction failed: ", err);
  });
```

and don't forget to import `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

Comment: I have the feeling that this wont work, as `this` refers to a different context. Maybe change the function to fat arrow notation?

Comment: yes you are right, it runs on another thread. i updated answer

Comment: Hi @Hareesh, I tried using the code and while it prints successfully in the console, it doesn't update my database, but it also doesn't give any errors. I updated the code in the question, did I do something wrong?

Comment: I added this.upvote += 1, it works now but it keeps stacking whenever I click the button more than once, e.g. first click = 1, second click = 3, third click = 6